# WidgetKit not showing any debugger logs in Xcode 14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, widgetkit

I am having a problem with WidgetKit in Xcode 14 which is the debugger doesn't show any logs at all! even a simple `print()`. I have tried different ways

- Running on the real device
- Clean DerivedData folder
- Attaching to process using Debug -> Attach to process -> Likely
  targets
- Restart Mac and Xcode
- Following Debugging Widgets from Apple docs:
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/debugging-widgets

and other possible solutions found here! but still, no luck, have you any suggestions to fix this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem I succeeded in having breakpoints working but no logs

Answer (score 1):

It is no longer recommended to use print() to get messages to the console. It's a little more complicated now, but the new method also has some advantages.

Add the following to the top of your code.

```
import os.log

extension OSLog {
    private static var subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!

    /// Logs the view cycles like viewDidLoad.
    static let viewCycle = OSLog(subsystem: subsystem, category: "viewcycle")
}
```

Now you can do replace your print() statements with something like this:

```
Logger.viewCycle.info("View did load!")
```

If you open the standard MacOs [console.app](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/console/welcome/mac), you'll see the messages printed and can filter by device/category/process/message.

[credit](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/oslog-unified-logging/)